# Comma separated all attached image ID numbers except featured image ID number

Tags: posts, images

I used this great one liner code to display with comma separated ID numbers of all attached images to a post. But I couldnt extract the featured image ID from it. How can I extract the featured image ID by using and adding this nice code?

```
$ids = join( ',', wp_list_pluck( get_attached_media('image' ), 'ID' ) );
```

got from [How do I create Comma Separated list of attached image ids?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169148/how-do-i-create-comma-separated-list-of-attached-image-ids)

Answer (score 1):

If we want to exclude the *featured post image* then here's the one-liner updated:

```
$ids = join( ',', wp_filter_object_list( get_attached_media('image' ), [ 'ID' => get_post_thumbnail_id() ], 'NOT', 'ID' ) );
```

here it's expanded:

```
$ids = join( 
    ',',                                       // join array by comma
    wp_filter_object_list( 
        get_attached_media('image' ),          // fetch attached images
        [ 'ID' => get_post_thumbnail_id() ],   // filter ID equal to featured image ID
        ' NOT',                                // filter operator: NOT
        'ID'                                   // pluck the IDs (only include)
    ) 
);
```